# Shortcut For Adding Bullet Point In Mac's Notes Application

Tags: macos, keyboard, high-sierra, notes.app

Does anyone know if there is a way I can start a bullet point list in the updated Notes app that comes with the MacOS with a keyboard shortcut that looks

1. like this

---

- or this

I use the app in class a lot because I like the snappy UI and, would like to add them quicker to improve my workflow.
I know that in Microsoft Word the shortcuts would be..

a. Start a bullet point list `*` then `tab`

b. Insert a LISTNUM `⌘ + ⌥ + shift + L` [Microsoft Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-for-mac-3256d48a-7967-475d-be81-a6e3e1284b25)

c. Most times `⌥ + 8` can be used to insert a bullet too [Discussion Shortcut Insert bullet](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1381905)

`⌘ + shift + L` gives me a pretty button list but not just a plain old list. My guess is that this [link](https://support.apple.com/guide/notes/keyboard-shortcuts-apd46c25187e/mac) contains all shortcuts and for a simple

- bullet point

I'll have to do it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>8</kbd>  at the start of a new line will generate a bullet list.

Adding further new lines will add more bullets, until you add 2 new lines, then it will revert to 'plain'

Same for a numbered list, but start new line 1. then space

[image]